# Updating Table from a select replace()

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table where I've done a select replace but the values do not stick to the table. How do I update it such that the values of the select statement is reflected in the table.

```
update MobileDb set Mobile = select replace(Mobile, " ", "") from MobileDB;
```

essentially MobileDB is the table and Mobile is the field name. This table has only one column called Mobile.

Comment: This is not valid SQL; the values do not "stick" because you get an error (which you decided to keep a secret).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UPDATE MobileDb 
SET Mobile = REPLACE(Mobile, " ", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

use single quote :

```
select replace(Mobile, ' ', '') from MobileDB;
```